# Tracking user action in react and .NET

Tags: asp.net, reactjs

I have a site (with frontend react and backebnd in .net). I want to analyze what does user do in my site.

Is there any tool to do it? (Prefering free tool).

Thanks,
Alice

Answer (score 0):

You can always use Google Analytics. There is a library called ReactGA, which makes it easier for you to implement.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment.I want tool that analyze actions and tools standalone (without connecting to remote server)